# Enumerate all files with Rx

Tags: c#, reactive-programming

This is my attempt for more responsive interface during pupulating listbox with large number of files (or from slow network folders) during file search.

```
IDisposable observer;
IObservable<IList<FileInfo>> bufferedFiles;
ObservableCollection<object> _fileCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();

public void EnumerateFiles(string myfolder, string filter)
{
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(myfolder);

    this.bufferedFiles =
     Observable.Buffer(dir.EnumerateFiles(filter, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.2), 100, NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .ObserveOn(syncContext); 

    this.observer = this.bufferedFiles.Subscribe(outputFiles);
}

private void outputFiles(IEnumerable<FileInfo> FI)
{
    foreach (var file in FI)
        _fileCollection.Add(file);
    Debug.Print(_fileCollection.Count.toString());
}
```

Explanation of buffer follows:

> ...each element of an observable sequence into a buffer that’s sent
>   out when either it’s full or a given amount of time has elapsed.

So I expect on local drive listbox will get 100 items at a time, while on slow network it will output whatever buffer collects within .2 seconds (as long as it is less than 100 iteme). I want enumeration on other thread while observing must obviously be on dispatcher.

Problem is that UI is frozen.

Comment: Against which code do you compare that it's slower? Did you test it more than once? And when you specify an Interval(TimeSpan) it start's after the interval expired. When you want it to start immediately specify StartWith(0).

Comment: @MartijnvanPut slower than without Rx and just enumerate files and .Add within foreach

Comment: Why don't you just call ToObservable on the dir.EnumerateFiles and observe it on the synccContext and then check the performance again? I'm wondering why you are using the Interval and Zip/Buffer with the enumeration of files? is this construction the same for non-RX

Comment: @MartijnvanPut StartWith(0) eliminated annoying delay. Thanks! With Zip/Buffer I am trying to force output whether .2 seconds elapsed or 1000 items are found first. This way user would have at least something after .2s. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Interval repeats every .2 seconds when i understand you correctly you want the following: dir.EnumerableFiles().ToObservable().Take(1000).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.2)). This code takes the First 1000 or Timeouts (it throws an TimeoutException so catch it)

Comment: @MartijnvanPut Actually, if timeouts is should output whatever is buffered but if 1000 items are found before timeout it outputs all 1000. Can you please also write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61784/discussion-between-martijn-van-put-and-milo-s).

Answer (score 2):

The Observable.Interval repeats the action every specified timespan. Buffer is just enough to accomplish your wish.

```
private async Task OutputFiles(IEnumerable<object> paths) 
{ 
    foreach (var o in paths) 
    {
         await Task.Delay(1); // Delay so the UI can update the List
        _fileCollection.Add(o); 
    }

    this.observer = Observable.Buffer(
      dir.EnumerateFiles(
         myfile, 
         System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories, 
         true).ToObservable(Scheduler.Default), 
      TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5),                      
      Scheduler.Default)
   .ObserveOn(syncContext)
   .Subscribe(async x => await outputFiles(x));
}
```